# What kind of code is this?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have some coded strings in my database which reference the categories of my site.

They look like this

```
a:1:{i:0;s:12:"TVRFNE1EYz0=";}
```

I'm wondering what they are so I can create them all to use in a CSV file as creating them on my site is very time consuming.

Thanks

Oh actually I really don't think this is possible. It happens when I select a category on my blog then save. Then that is what is put into the database. I'm trying to figure out a way to create all the searlized codes for each category to use in a CSV file. I guess maybe impossible as I will need to know the structure of how it is made?

Answer (score 4):

As @Codeacula said, it's PHP serialization at work:

```
a:1:{i:0;s:12:"TVRFNE1EYz0=";}
```

translates into: array of one element, containing an integer 0 and a string of 12 characters spelling `"TVRFNE1EYz0="`. It's quite human-readable.

Now, what "TVRFNE1EYz0=" is is anyone's guess. You should probably look into your application for the meaning of that.

To generate serialized strings, use PHP `serialize` function. Or, start counting letters in your strings. Or use [this](http://unserialize.net/).

Comment: The actual string data is doubly encoded Base 64. In this case, "TVRFNE1EYz0=" is "11807". :)

Comment: Oh, this is so not cool. I'm telling my mother you took my answer and added more words. /upvote

Comment: Lol, here's a backvote. :) I did not intend to detract from your firsthood, just provide more details OP wanted.

Answer (score 2):

That looks like a serialized string from PHP. You'll need to run `unserialize` to use it. [Reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php)

Comment: Is there an online tool I can use to turn words into these strings?

Comment: http://unserialize.net/ seems to be, off a simple google. [Google Query](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=php+serialize+online)

Comment: Oh actually I really don't think this is possible. It happens when I select a category on my blog then save. Then that is what is put into the database. I'm trying to figure out a way to create all the searlized codes for each category to use in a CSV file. I guess maybe impossible as I will need to know the structure of how it is made?

Comment: You can unserialize the data, convert it to JSON, make changes and use that tool to serialize it again. Or, before it's serialized, write a little code to add/change something in it.

Comment: Reply to comment edit: Then you will need to query the database and run their function against the data being provided. It's likely doable, but without knowing specifics I can only say that you'll have to gather the data, make a version of the function your blog runs so that you can pass it the data and it returns the serialized string, and then save that to a CSV file.

Comment: If they're all this simple, they're trivial to construct. Given an input string ("11807" in the example), just wrap it in a serialized string like `a:1:{i:0;s:<encoded_length>:"<encoded>";}` and change the data and the length to the actual values (length of the resulting string value after two base 64 encodes etc).

Comment: Okey sounds very tricky. I'm a complete noob. I guess I shall just have to keep doing this manually. All 600 of them :-( lol

Comment: @mark Au contraire. For each category you have, you construct a string using the template I provided, where you **base 64 encode the category number twice to get a string, and then in the template replace <encoded> with the string, and <encoded_length> with the number of characters in the string**. In PHP, I have no idea how to do it. I'd use Perl. :)